# Storing different types in a single Hashmap

Tags: generics, caching, rust, typing, unsafe

A bit of context to prevent xy:

I want to build a cache for my system. There are Type pairs consisting of `IdType` and `EndpointType` in a 1:1 relationship. Every `IdType` only ever refers to one `EndpointType` and vice versa. The `Id` trait (see code below) is not required, it only exists in my current iteration of trying to make this work.

There are way too many different types of endpoints - and usually an application will only use a small subset of them - to justify statically building a cache per endpoint and holding that in memory. Additionally, I want to be able to add new endpoints without touching any code related to caching or the client itself.

The `Endpoint` trait objects are not object safe and there is no way to make them object safe due to associated `const`s, `Sized` and methods not using `self` to make use of compile time optimizations.

I came up with the idea of storing them as kind of `Any` type. Now I like type safety, so I tried to restrict it a bit more. After failing to find a satisfying solution, I still have several issues with my idea:

1. How do I make this approach work?
2. Is there a better solution?
3. Is this sound? Why?
4. Is there a way to make it sound?
5. Can I achieve this without unsafe?

[Link to the rust playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=9c7c807e588462a0c5f979920717c1c2)

```rs
use std::sync::Mutex;
use std::collections::HashMap;

pub trait Endpoint: Sized {
    type Id;
}

pub trait Id {
    type Endpoint;
}

pub struct Client {
    cache: Mutex<Cache>,
}

impl Client {
    fn get<T: Endpoint>(&self, id: T::Id) -> T {
        if let Some(result) = self.cache.lock().unwrap().get(id) {
            return result;
        }
        todo!()
    }
}

pub struct Cache {
    map: HashMap<Box<dyn Id>, Box<dyn Endpoint>>,
}

impl Cache {
    fn get<T: Id>(&self, id: T) -> Option<T::Endpoint> {
        if let Some(endpoint) = self.map.get(Box::new(id)) {
            let endpoint: Box<T::Endpoint> = unsafe { std::mem::transmute(endpoint) };
            Some(endpoint)
        } else {
            None
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd strongly recommend going with `Box<dyn Any>` over `std::mem::transmute`. A fairly common pattern is to have a `HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>`. `TypeId` is a type that can be used to distinguish between other types, and it's `Eq` and `Hash` impls work how you'd expect: if the types are the same, the type ids are equal. So you could have something roughly like:

```rust
struct Cache {
  map: HashMap<TypeId, Box<dyn Any>>,
}

impl Cache {
  fn get<T>(&self) -> Option<&T> {
    let type_id = TypeId::of::<T>();
    let any = self.map.get(&type_id)?;
    any.downcast_ref()
  }
}
```

This can act like a rough lookup table that associates a type with a single value of that type. If there is a `Box<dyn Any>` that is associated with the type id for `T`, but points to a value of some other type, you won't get UB, you'll just get `None`.

This sort of primitive can be used to build a more complex cache around it. For example, you could have a struct that wraps this that provides access, but it only supports keys of type `(T, <T as Id>::Endpoint)`.

The key point is to use `Any` and `downcast_*` methods to avoid unsafe.

`std::mem::transmute` is one of the more dangerous unsafe functions, and should largely be seen as a last resort. From the docs:

> `transmute` is **incredibly** unsafe. There are a vast number of ways to cause undefined behaviour with this function. `transmute` should be the absolute last resort

I'd also add, this pattern is common enough that there's probably a crate that provides a type safe interface, a quick search yielded this: https://crates.io/crates/anymap, though I can't speak for this crate's quality in particular

Edit:

If you also want to be able to distinguish between multiple instances of the same `Id`/`Endpoint` pair type, you could modify it to store a hashmap with the keys having a type `(TypeId, u64)`, where the `u64` is the result of hashing the original key (a bit like a SQL composite key):

```rust
struct Cache {
  map: HashMap<(TypeId, u64), Box<dyn Any>>,
}

impl Cache {
    fn insert<T>(&mut self, id: T::Id, endpoint: T)
    where
        T: Endpoint + 'static,
        T::Id: Hash,
    {
        let type_id = TypeId::of::<T>();
        let hash = {
            let mut hasher = DefaultHasher::new();
            id.hash(&mut hasher);
            hasher.finish()
        };

        self.map.insert((type_id, hash), Box::new(endpoint));
    }

    fn get<T>(&self, id: T::Id) -> Option<&T>
    where
        T: Endpoint + 'static,
        T::Id: Hash,
    {
        let type_id = ...;
        let hash = ...;

        let option_any = self.map.get(&(type_id, hash));
        option_any.and_then(|any| any.downcast_ref())
    }
}
```

This lets you have multiple `FooEndpoint`s (with `FooId`s), as well as `BarEndpoint`s (and `BarId`s), while avoiding transmute/unsafe, all with a single map lookup. Hopefully I read your question more accurately this time ;p

P.S. I have no idea if this particular way of obtaining a `u64` hash is "good", I've never actually had to do this before (I've only ever used the `Hash` trait with `std::collections::HashMap/HashSet`). Might be worth doing some googling to make sure this isn't doing something horrible

Comment: Thank you for this elaborate write-up! This is exactly the pattern that I started with and wanted to avoid, as I would need to make 2 lookups in nested hashmaps to get to my result. Do you think there is a way to avoid the 2nd lookup? `transmute` is already used quite heavily to interoperate with dynamic runtime code, but ofc I would enjoy ways to circumvent it.

Comment: You could avoid the second lookup by only using this structure to store types like `(T, <T as Id>::Endpoint)`, i.e. a tuple containing only the pair, then your public API only provides a function like `get_endpoint<T: Id>()`, and the implementation of that function calls `cache.get::<(T, T::Endpoint)>()`. This way you avoid a second map lookup and also unsafe code

Comment: I think one of us misunderstood the other. What you call `T` is an id that identifies structs of type `T::Endpoint`. I still need to have a `Hashmap<T, T::Endpoint>` with that approach.

Comment: Ah I think I misread your question, I think it's still possible to make work though, I'll edit my answer with an idea

Comment: This got me onto the right path, I will use a variant of this proposed solution, thanks a lot